# Sql server replication - Slow transfer, even with compressed FTP file

Tags: sql, sql-server, ftp, replication, transactional-replication

I have a transactional pull replication running.

The publisher and the distributor are both SQL server 2012.
The subscriber is a SQL express 2012.

I have setup the server to get the initial snapshot from a compressed FTP file. The data transfered is already filtered to the minimum required. Those parts work fine.

Where it seems to have a problem is when the subscriber tries to apply the snapshot. On a high bandwidth network, the snapshot is applied in less then one minute. On a low bandwidth network, the snapshot can take up to 20 minutes to apply.

On the 20 minutes, downloading the FTP snapshot from the low bandwidth subscriber takes 2 minutes.After this, applying the decompressed local files is taking the other 18 minutes.

The ftp snapshots are not supposed to be run locally ?

Why applying local file on the local server takes 18 minutes on a low bandwidth network subscriber and only takes few seconds on high bandwidth network subcriber ?

Thanks !

Comment: You need to understand how snapshot works to know the impact of bandwidth :https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151734(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: From the article, for the distribution agent running at the subscriber, it says :

1.Establishes a connection to the Distributor.
2.Examines the MSrepl_commands and MSrepl_transactions tables in the distribution database on the Distributor. The agent reads the location of the snapshot files from the first table and Subscriber synchronization commands from both tables.

Is this really means even if you run the agent at the subscriber, you must always communicate with the distributor in realtime to apply a snapsnot ? We cannot just download and apply it ?